# In R, how do I simplify an XmlNodeSet into a vector?

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I've used `getNodeSet` in the XML library and applied some xpath to an XML document. (Basically there's an inventory list and I'm pulling out the names of each item of inventory.) Trouble is, it returns a class of `XmlNodeSet` (which, yeah, makes sense). The object is a bunch of 1-element lists that I'd like to simplify into a single character vector.

This should be simple but I'm honestly blanking on even where to start because I'm not sure how to work with the XmlNodeSet object.

**Edit:** I've gotten a little farther but not much. I've created my `names` object this way:

```
names <- getNodeSet(collection.xml, "//name/text()")
```

If I run `names[[1]]` it spits out exactly what I want, just the name. Strangely, `names[[1]]` works and `names[[2]]` works, but `names[[1:2]]` returns an error. I'm not sure how to use standard R recursion functions like `sapply` to say "For this object `names`, call `names[[x]]`, where `x` begins at 1 and ends at `length(names)`."

Comment: `sapply(myNodeset, xmlValue)`?

Comment: That doesn't work because the xpath query actually returns the text nodes, so there's no `XMLValue' to retrieve.

Comment: @RichardScriven That should have worked, but it's super strange.

If I call `class(unlist(names))` the result is `"list"`

Comment: Wait, wait, @lukeA was right. I just typo'd when I tried it.